# Postgres stops about every 2-3 weeks. Says it was shutdown by an admin but I'm the only admin

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown

Postgresql 12.8 on Ubuntu 20.04.1

This system is running a single java application that talks to the database.  Only one user can log into the system (expedite) and only that user runs anything.  No external database connections are allowed.  I don't have any code that I know of that actually attempts to shutdown postgresql.  And yet, about every two to three weeks, it simply stops. The log file is below.  I don't even know HOW to send a fast shutdown request!

The system is usually idle when this occurs.  I might be logged in but my software is not doing anything at the time, based upon my own logs.

I do have a script that I call when my java code detects that the database is no longer accepting requests.  This calls systemctl is-active to see if the service is down or not.  Even without any code running (ps -ef lists nothing about postgresql), it says the service is still active.  That might be a "feature" of systemctl but...

I'm not a database expert so a pointer to where I can look or a suggestion on how I might track this down would be greatly appreciated.  Note that when I restart the database, everything is back up for another 2-3 weeks.

This happens on 4 different systems that are configured the same way, two are VMs, the other two are running on dedicated PCs.

```
2021-08-14 06:52:30.616 MDT [1436] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2021-08-14 06:52:30.676 MDT [1436] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2021-08-14 06:52:30.681 MDT [1092072] expedite@expedite FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2021-08-14 06:52:30.683 MDT [1436] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 1533) exited with exit code 1
2021-08-14 06:52:30.685 MDT [1528] LOG:  shutting down
2021-08-14 06:52:30.989 MDT [1436] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

NOTE:  I also looked in the syslog around that date/time and did not see anything unusual.

Thanks in advance!

Bruce

Comment: Hey, can you examine what systemd did at the time of these events?
If you run `journalctl -u postgresql@12-main` you should probably see something.
You can use --since and --until with `journalctl` to specify a certain time range.

I have a suspicion that this might be due to automatic updates...

Comment: Oh interesting.  This takes a long time to run (sometimes weeks) so the next time this happens, I'll check for this.  Your suspicion has merit.  

I have added automatic restarts to my application via a script so I will add the journalctl call at the same time before I restart it. 

Thanks!